# Moving jquery accordion elements from one accordion to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Bit of an odd one, this. I have two jquery accordion entities, and on click of an item in one accordion, I want to dynamically add it to a second accordion, and hide it in the original.

This currently works great moveing from A to B, and on moving back from B to A, BUT when I move an item back to original accordion, any subsequent moves from A to B screw up.

Here's a jsfiddle example of what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/waveydavey/CAYth/ . Note I am compeltely aware that the code is ugly - I'm just learning this stuff. Please feel free to suggest ways that are 10 times better. Do the following:

- Run the fiddle.
- Click on the "+" of each item to move to accordion 2
- All move really well.

Now do this:

- Run the fiddle.
- Click on any "+" to move to 2nd accordion
- Click on "x" on moved item, it re-appears in first set
- Click on any "+" item to add to second set
- Display completely messes up for accordion item

Any advice would be massively appreciated.

The jsfiddle code is:

```
    $(function() {
 // create accordion entities
 $('#avAccordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
 $('#assignedAccordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
 $('.accordionAdd').click(function(){
        // destroy the accordion, prior to rebuilding
        $('#avAccordion').accordion('destroy');
        // get the h3 part and tweak it's contents
        var h3bit = $(this).parent().clone();
        $(h3bit).removeClass('freeContacts').addClass('assignedContacts');
        $(h3bit).children('span').removeClass('ui-icon-circle-plus accordionAdd').addClass('ui-icon-circle-close accordionDel');
        // get the div part after the h3
        var divbit = $(this).parent().next().clone();
        // rebuild original accordion
        $( "#avAccordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });
        // move contents to other accordion
     $('#assignedAccordion').append(h3bit)
         .append(divbit)
         .accordion('destroy')
         .accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });
        // hide original accordion entry
        $(this).parent().hide();
        //attach click handler to new item
        $('.accordionDel').click(function(){
            dropAssignedContact(this);
            return false;
        })
        return false;
    });

    function dropAssignedContact(obj){
        // unhide right hand object with appropriate data-id attr
        var id = $(obj).parent().attr('data-id');
       // delete myself
        $(obj).parent().remove();
        // unhide original
        $('.freeContacts[data-id='+id+']').show();
        $('#assignedAccordion').accordion('destroy').accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KTWEd/

```
function dropAssignedContact(obj){
    // unhide right hand object with appropriate data-id attr
    var id = $(obj).parent().attr('data-id'); 

   // delete myself
    $(obj).parent().next().remove();   // <---   Removes the adjacent div
    $(obj).parent().remove();

    // unhide original
    $('.freeContacts[data-id='+id+']').show();
    $('#assignedAccordion').accordion('destroy').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: Stunningly simple, and completely non-obvious to me! Many, many thanks, I can stop tearing my hair out now.